# Month Displaying Earlier Than Expected

Tags: views

I have the following code to print last month once a new month starts.

$prevmonth = date('F Y', strtotime("last month"));
print $prevmonth;

The problem I encountered recently was that last month was printed before this month (August) begins.  E.g. July was showing although it was still July 31.

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about the timezone settings ? This could be a lead.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

Your time zone settings may not be set correctly so I would check that.  If those are correct I would suggest a better way then to rely on strtotime:

```
$date1 = new DateTime(); 
$month_ago = new DateInterval( "P1M" ); 
$month_ago->invert = 1; //Make it negative. 
$date1->add( $month_ago );

$prevmonth = date('F Y', $date1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, chadpeppers.  I tried your code but it didn't do anything for me.  My co-worker was able to help. The following code fix the problem:

```
$prevmonth = date('F Y', strtotime("first day of last month"));
print $prevmonth;
```